# Find the smallest item in a singly-linked List and move to the head?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I had a quiz recently and this is what the question looked like:-

You may use the following Node class:

```
class Node:
  """Lightweight, nonpublic class for storing a singly linked node."""
  __slots__ = 'element', 'next'       # streamline memory usage

  def __init__(self, element, next):  # initialize node's fields
    self.element = element            # reference to user's element
    self.next = next                  # reference to next node
```

Assume you have a singly-linked list of unique integers. Write a Python method that traverses this list to find the smallest element, removes the node that contains that value, and inserts the smallest value in a new node at the front of the list. Finally, return the head pointer. For simplicity, you may assume that the node containing the smallest value is not already at the head of the list (ie, you will never have to remove the head node and re-add it again).

Your method will be passed the head of the list as a parameter (of type Node), as in the following method signature:

def moveSmallest(head):
You may use only the Node class; no other methods (like size(), etc) are available. Furthermore, the only pointer you have is head (passed in as a parameter); you do not have access to a tail pointer.

For example, if the list contains:

5 → 2 → 1 → 3
the resulting list will contain:

1 → 5 → 2 → 3
Hint 1: There are several parts to this question; break the problem down and think about how to do each part separately.

Hint 2: If you need to exit from a loop early, you can use the break command.

Hint 3: For an empty list or a list with only one element, there is nothing to do!

My answer:

```
def moveSmallest(h):
 if h==None or h.next==None:
   return h

 # find part
 temp=h
 myList=[]
 while temp!=None:
   myList.append(temp.element)
   temp=temp.next
 myList.sort()
 sv=myList[0]

 # remove part
 if h.element==sv and h.next!=None:
   h=h.next
 else:
   start=h
   while start!=None:
     if start.next.element==sv and start.next.next!=None:
       start.next=start.next.next
       break
     if start.next.element==sv and start.next.next==None:
       start.next=None
       break
     start=start.next

 # Insert part
 newNode=Node(sv)
 newNode.next=h
 h=newNode
 return h
```

Mark received=10/30

Feedback on my answer:

"Not supposed to use sorting; searching the list should be the way we've covered in class.

You're advancing too far ahead in the list without checking whether nodes exist.

Review the 'singly-linked list' slides and answer this question as the examples suggest."

As you can see I am finding the element in the list and removing it and then adding it to the list as a head node. I ran this code and it works fine. As you can see in the feedback he says "You're advancing too far ahead in the list without checking whether nodes exist." which is taken care by the first if statement in my answer and for "Not supposed to use sorting; searching the list should be the way we've covered in class." I believe my mistake was to use the list at the first place but given the code the final score should be or be more than 20/30. Can you guys please check this or give your opinion on this feedback?

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see in the feedback he says "You're advancing too far ahead
>   in the list without checking whether nodes exist." which is taken care
>   by the first if statement in my answer

It's not taken care of. The first if-statement of your function just checks to see if the head exists and that the node following the head exists as well (basically, asserting that you have at least two nodes in the linked list).

What you have:

```
if h.element==sv and h.next!=None:
   h=h.next
 else:
   start=h
   while start!=None:
     if start.next.element==sv and start.next.next!=None:
```

If you enter the while loop, you only know the following things:

1. Your linked list has at least two elements
2. h.element != sv or h.next == None
3. The current node is not None

The node following the current node (start.next), however, may be None at some point - when you reach the end of your linked list. Therefore, you are trying to access a node that doesn't exist.

Here's how I would have done it. I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure this works:

```
def moveSmallest(head):

    if head is None or head.next is None:
        return head

    # First, determine the smallest element.
    # To do this, we need to visit each node once (except the head).
    # Create a cursor that "iterates" through the nodes
    # (The cursor can start at the 2nd element because we're guaranteed the head will never have the smallest element.)
    cursor = head.next
    current_minimum = head.next.element
    while cursor is not None:
        if current_minimum > cursor.element:
            # We've found the new minimum.
            current_minimum = cursor.element
        cursor = cursor.next

    # At this point, current_minimum is the smallest element.
    # Next, go through the linked list again until right before we reach the node with the smallest element.
    cursor = head
    while cursor.next is not None:
        if cursor.next.element == current_minimum:
            # We want to reconnect the arrows.
            if cursor.next.next is None:
                cursor.next = None
            else:
                cursor.next = cursor.next.next
            break

    new_node = Node(current_minimum, head)
    head = new_node
    return head
```

Comment: By if statement I meant this { if h==None or h.next==None:
   return h} which checks if there is no node or 1 node which removes the possibility of going to while loop at the first place

Comment: Yes, I know - we're both talking about the same if-statement. As you've said, this if-statement terminates the function prematurely if you have less than two nodes in your linked list. That's all it does. What if I pass in a linked list with three nodes? I will definitely reach the while loop.

Comment: Sorry to post two comments in a row... just to be clear, in addition, you will never enter the body of the second if-statement `if h.element==sv and h.next!=None:`. Neither of these conditions will ever be true. The header's element will never be equal to the smallest value, because the instructions say so, and the header is guaranteed to have a next node, because if it didn't you would have returned from the function in the first if-statement. Therefore, if you have two or more nodes in your linked list, you will always enter the while loop.